# how to connect with ajax to php and show the results with a button onclick

Tags: html, ajax

i do this but didnt connect to php and show me the response xml can anyone tell me how that gone to work

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function showhint(str) {
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

        ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = ajax.responseXML;
            }
        };

        ajax.open("GET","xmlconvert.php?q="+str,true);
        ajax.send();                  
    }
 </script> 

<script>
    function void  functionvalue(){
    var bookname = document.getElementById('book').value;
    return bookname;
    }
</script>

<form id="keyword" >
    <input type="text" name="value" id="book">
    <br>
    <button  onclick="showhint(functionvalue())">Search By Title</button>
</form>
<div id="results">
```

php->mysql query:

```
$a=$_GET["q"];
$sql="select * from `book` where title=$q;";
```

Answer (score 0):

do you need put an echo in php, this is return to ajax like a text, and you can parse in js

Comment: no in php i have the books from the mysql that i convert it in xml - thats work with a simple query select * from books i want to get the value(title) that user put and do it query  as you see on the end of my post

Answer (score 0):

based on your question, you need post some input type text only by click radio button for insert or  etc, all you need include jquery then by event click execute ajax jquery her eis [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ixZA7W53fCULCVPxXCNn?p=preview)

then this is code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>

    <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:radio[name='radio']").click(function(){

     var nama= $("input[name=name]").val();
     $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "your-php-is-here",
            data: { nama: nama }
        });
     })
   });

    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
      <input type="text" name="name" >

      <input type="radio" name="radio"> Click it

  </body>

</html>
```